# C++ How do I inherit from a template class, to a template class, with the same arguments

Tags: c++, oop, templates, c++11, inheritance

This question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895775/class-template-inheritance-c) *except* for the fact that I read said question and still couldn't figure out what was wrong. Edit: No it doesn't the cause of this error is different.

I am trying to do this:

```
template<typename T>
class base
{

protected:

    base() {}

    virtual ~base() {}

    virtual void method(void* const voidp) const = 0;

};

template<typename T>
class child : public base<T> // ERROR: child is not a template type
{

public:

    child(std::vector<T> arg)
        : _arg{arg}
    {
    }

    virtual ~child() {}

    void method(void* const voidp) const
    {
        for(template std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = _arg.begin(); it != _arg.end(); ++ it)
        {
            method2(voidp, *it);
        }
    }

protected:

    std::vector<T> _arg;

};
```

I am slightly confused since this appears to be identical to the linked example, unless I am mistaken?

Edit: This is `method2`

```
void method2(void* const voidp, const double& arg) // second argument comes in both double and float formats
{
}

// so there is also a: void method2(void* const voidp, const float& arg)
```

Comment: `std::vector<T>::iterator` should be `typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator`, and the `method(voidp, *it);` call inside is wrong - there is no such function

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Ah sorry that's a mistake, let me change that. The problem with my minimal example was that I messed it up and only gave you half of it.

Comment: The constructor of class `child` has a sintax error: `_arg{arg}` should be `_arg(arg)`.

Comment: @enzom83 There is no syntax error - this is C++ 11

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd see

> "// ERROR: child is not a template type"

However one obvious thing you're missing is `typename` before `std::vector<T>::iterator it`

Also it should be `const_iterator`

```
for(typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = _arg.begin(); 
     it != _arg.end(); 
      ++it)
{
    //method(voidp, *it); //<--- Assuming you've this somewhere not shown in current post
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem... Why have you got typename before the iterator there?

Comment: Because `std::vector<T>::const_iterator` is dependent type name. Also you'll have to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you feel that's not the problem with current post

Comment: @user3728501 Well see [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50c8f20c66ccbe61) and now fix as told

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the same problem as me, it may be that you made a `friend class` definition elsewhere in your code? After playing around with my code on different systems with different compilers and compiler options, I fluked making it compile. I believe this was because at some point I removed a line from a file from the project, and when inspecting this file, I think it used to have a friend class definition in there. I assume that this caused the compiler to think I wasn't writing a template class? Although I am not completely convinced that this is the reason.

Answer (score -1):

There is no likely reason for that certain error, unless perhaps there is a class `child` predeclared without a class template.

One cause may be that you should initialise a member using `()` rather than `{}`:

```
child(std::vector<T> arg)
        : _arg{arg}
    {
    }
```

should be corrected to:

```
child(std::vector<T> arg)
        : _arg(arg)
    {
    }
```

It's also better to pass by const reference:

```
child(const std::vector<T>& arg)
        : _arg(arg)
    {
    }
```

---

However, there are a couple of other things that may be improved to aid the program:

---

The for loop will not compile:

```
for(std::vector<T>::iterator it = _arg.begin(); it != _arg.end(); ++ it)
    {
        method2(voidp, *it);
    }
```

`T` is a dependent name which means that `std::vector<T>::iterator` should be corrected to `typename std::vector<T>::iterator`. You can read more about this [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

However, `std::vector<T>::iterator` should also be corrected to `std::vector<T>::const_iterator`. As the function `method` is `const`, the `const` means that the function will promise not to modify *any* of the members of the class. However, the `iterator begin()` function in the vector is not const-qualified which means that the compiler does not know whether you want to modify the members or not. As a result the overload `const_iterator begin() const` has to be used so that the compiler explicitly knows you will not modify any members.

Another note: if you are using `c++11`, you can make the loop a lot shorter by using the range-for loop:

```
for(const auto& x : _arg)
{
    method2(voidp, x);
}
```

---

There is no need to declare `public:` twice in the class; once `public` has been declared once, everything following will be public until the compiler reaches another `protected`/`private` keyword, and vice-versa for the other keywords.

Note that the default access level for a `class` is `private` and is `public` for a `struct`. Thus your class can be slightly amended to this:

```
template<typename T>
class child : public base<T>
{
public:
    child(const std::vector<T>& arg)
        : _arg(arg)
    {
    }

    virtual ~child() {}

    void method(const void* voidp) const
    {
        for(typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = _arg.begin(); it != _arg.end(); ++ it)
        {
            method2(voidp, *it);
        }
    }

protected:
    std::vector<T> _arg;
};
```

Same for your `base` class:

```
template<typename T>
class base
{
protected:
    base() {}
    virtual ~base() {}
    virtual void method(const void* voidp) const = 0;
};
```

---

Be consistent with where you put the `const` keyword in your function declarations:

You have: `void* const voidp` and then `const double& arg`. As shown, the `const` keyword is inconsistently placed - one after and one before the type:

It would be better to do either: `const void* voidp, const double& arg` or `void* const voidp, double const& arg` for consistency.

---

To finish, I compiled the below code using MSVC and it worked fine:

```
template<typename T>
    class base
    {
    protected:
        base() {}
        virtual ~base() {}
        virtual void method(const void* voidp) const = 0;
    };

template<typename T>
    class child : public base<T>
    {
    public:
        child(const std::vector<T>& arg)
            : _arg(arg)
        {
        }

        virtual ~child() {}

        void method(const void* voidp) const
        {
            for(typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = _arg.begin(); it != _arg.end(); ++it)
            {
                method2(voidp, *it);
            }
        }

    protected:
        std::vector<T> _arg;
    };
```

---

Hope this helps:)

Comment: To comment on some of your points: Why should I initialize with () rather than {}?

Comment: More comments: Yes I copied and pasted this quickly, so okay it should be const_iterator, same for public/private tags, and also template in for loop - I have modified the example to take care of this, these are not the main issues here

Comment: Finally I am not a believer in "auto" so I choose not to use it... I don't like that sloppy way of programming...

Comment: Oh, and I can't see the `const` problem? Where abouts is this?

Comment: @user3728501 - the `const` problem is not massively a problem as such; it is just for consistency in your code. As in it is better to constantly put const before or after the type to just make the code more consistent.

Comment: Obviously - but that's not why my code doesn't compile

Comment: @user3728501 - and the reason for using `()` instead of `{}` as an in-class initializer is that MSVC does not like it

Comment: @user3728501 - do you have any other classes or functions at all in your code that could perhaps cause an error?

Comment: that's a problem with your compiler not my code. I am re-writing a test project to remove everything except this class.

Comment: @user3728501 - sorry but I'm not too sure what the error in your code is - it seems to be completely fine and has compiled for me in MSVC... perhaps try a different compiler?

Comment: @user3728501 - sorry I couldn't help