# Inheriting from template abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have this code structure:

- An abstract class A (it has a pure virtual method)
- A class template B that inherits from A
- A class template C that inherits from B

```
class A
{
protected:
    int u;
    int z;

public:
    A(int uu,
      int zz)
    :u(uu),
     z(zz)
    {};

    int get() const
    {
    return u;
    };

    virtual void blah() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class B : public A
{
protected:
    std::vector<T> xxxx;
public:
    B(int uu,
      int zz,
      int bbb)
    :A(uu,
       zz)
    {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < bbb; i ++)
        xxxx[i] = 0;
    };

    virtual void blah()
    {
    u = u + 1;
    };
};

template <class T>
class C : public B<T>
{
protected:
    int qrqr;

public:
    C(int uu,
      int zz,
      int bbb,
      int qrqrqr)
    :B<T>(uu,
          zz,
          bbb),
     qrqr(qrqrqr)
    {
    };

    virtual void blah()
    {
    u = u + qrqr;
    };
};
```

When I compile I get this error:

```
 
error: 'u' was not declared in this scope
    at line:  u = u + qrqr;
```

Though `u` is clearly an element of C because A is a base of C through B.

I read here: [Class template inheritance C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895775/class-template-inheritance-c) that the proper way to inherit from class template is either to specialize the class or to have the inherited class to be template and this is what I did here. The compiler doesn't seem to complain about it anyway. Could it be because A is an abstract class?

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: fwiw, I never read the term "virtual class", `A` is an abstract class (because it has a pure virtual method)

Comment: Thanks I'll correct it

Comment: you missed the title and there are no template classes, they are called class templates. Sorry for the nitpicking ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with a *nondependent name* - the member you're referring to does not depend on the template parameter. The compiler does not look in dependent base classes (like `B<T>`) when looking up nondependent names (like `u`).

You can solve it by using

`this->u = this->u + qrqr;`

which specifies to the compiler which `u` you mean.

([coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/386ffc9445b1f800))

There are at least two other ways, by calling `B<T>::u`, or writing `using B<T>::u;` in the function before this line.

Read more about it [here](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html).

Comment: I would never have found that myself! Thanks for helping me fixing my problem so quickly! I learned something today :)

Comment: It is `B` which is template, not `A` ;).