# How to restrict a class template parameter to a certain subclass?

Tags: c++, templates, class-template, template-inheritance

This is what I am trying:

`C` is a template parameter that is either `SomeClass` or `SomeDerivedClass`:

```cpp
class SomeClass
{
protected:
  int ProtectedBaseClassMember;
  virtual void SomeFunctionFromBaseClass();
};

class SomeDerivedClass : public SomeClass { };
```

How to restrict `C` to subclasses of `SomeClass`?

```cpp
template<class C>
class SmuggleInBetween : public C
{
public:
  SmuggleInBetween()
  {
    // does not compile: unknown symbol "ProtectedBaseClassMember"
    ProtectedBaseClassMember = 5;
 
    // does compile, but ...
    SomeClass* Me = static_cast<SomeClass>(this);
    // ... member not accessible:
    Me->ProtectedBaseClassMember = 5;
  }
protected:
  // doesn't compile: "method with override specifier did not override any base class method"
  virtual void SomeFunctionFromBaseClass() override;
  double DoubleProperty;
};
```

I found the very related question: [Restrict C++ Template parameter to subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895775/class-template-inheritance-c),
but over there the author seems fine just restricting the template parameter w/o ever
accessing any symbols from the base class.

The use case for the templated `SmuggleInBetween` class is this:
I can create

```
class SomeImprovedClass : public SmuggleInBetween<SomeClass> { };
```

and

```
class SomeImprovedDerivedClass : public SmuggleInBetween<SomeDerivedClass> { };
```

without having to duplicate the code that I *smuggled in* via this pattern (if possible).

Btw, this happens in the context of Unreal Engine.
It might be that a solution that is possible in C++ still causes additional headache with the Unreal Header Tool that sometimes doesn't tolerate things that wander too far off the known paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
template<class C>
class SmuggleInBetween : public C
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<SomeClass, C>, "C must be a descendant of SomeClass");
    /* ... */
};
```

Of course, in general you could also use `std::enable_if_v<std::is_base_of_v<SomeClass, C>, ...>` if you need SFINAE; here I think `static_assert()` does the trick.

Comment: Yep it works. I was expecting more from C++ type inference. But without a good reason.

Comment: @ruben.moor In C++20, you can define a `template<class T, class U> concept Derived = std::is_base_of<U, T>::value;` and then use it as `template<Derived<Base> T> ...`.